# Passing string as argument adds escape characters

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, subprocess

I am accessing the subprocess module to call a shell function. Part of the function call is a string:

```
data = '\'{"data": [{"content": "blabla"}]}\''
```

when passing the string, I get the following error:

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output(['curl', '-d', data, 'http://service.location.com'], shell=True)
Error: raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output) ... returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I actually know the problem, it's that the string gets passed the way it looks to Python, escapes and all.

Using the console,

```
$ curl -d \'{"data": [{"content": "blabla"}]}\' http://service.location.com
```

gives the same error, while

```
$ curl -d '{"data": [{"content": "blabla"}]}' http://service.location.com
```

runs perfectly. Any ideas how to tell Python that it passes a string .. fully converted?

Comment: Have you tried `data = '{"data": [{"content": "blabla"}]}'` instead of `data = '\'{"data": [{"content": "blabla"}]}\''`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately both ' and " are required parts of the input format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `shell=True` parameter,  you don't need to split your actual command.

```
>>> check_output('''curl -d '{"data": [{"content": "blabla"}]}' http://service.location.com''', shell=True)
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="location no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en" ng-app="homeapp" ng-controller="AppCtrl"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="location no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en" ng-app="homeapp" ng-controller="AppCtrl"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="location no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" ng-app="homeapp" ng-controller="AppCtrl"> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="location no-js" ng-app="homeapp" ng-controller="AppCtrl"> <!--<![endif]-->\n\n<head>\n    <title>Location.com\xe2\x84\xa2 | Real Estate Locations for Sale and Rent</title>\n    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n\n                <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ajax.googleapis.com" />\n
```

OR

```
>>> data = """'{"data": [{"content": "blabla"}]}'"""
>>> check_output('''curl -d {0} http://service.location.com'''.format(data), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Shell=True`, try this:

```
data = '{"data": [{"content": "blabla"}]}'
from subprocess import check_output
check_output(['curl', '-d', data, 'http://service.location.com'])
```